# Fabric script executing does not finish

Tags: python, fabric

Here is my problem:

I have got a Python build script that executes several commands to produce a .air package. This part of the job is done correctly but after that, I'd like to deploy this file to a server.
I'm using a fabric script in ordrer to do that. Here are the lines:

```
if os.system(os.environ["FAB"] + "\\fab.exe " + version + " deploy") != 0:
    print("fab error")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

When I run this script, as said in the title, the fab.exe execution does not finish. If I run it separately in a cmd.exe window, there is no problem, so that means my SSH configuration seems to be OK.

I tried to print the ouput and the errors in files but when I kill the fab task, nothing is printed =(
Has anybody an idea about this problem? Is it possible that the execution of the build script has other rights than my windows account?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to note, you can import fabric itself directly and tell it to run it's tasks, so really you don't have to subprocess out. It's just python after all, and can be used as a library: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.1.1/usage/library.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it if I have some time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subprocess module to understand what happens

```
import subprocess
pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
pipexit = pipe.returncode
```

Then you may need a timeout, and for this you can use the pipe.poll() call, which allows to check if the subprocess is finished or not (then if after a certain time is not finished you may decide to kill it).

Comment: So I tried this and I got an error output: The system cannot find the path specified.

But which path? the path to fab.exe or path in the fabfile? Curious, curious... It runs correctly when I invoke it in a shell, but when the build server tries to execute it, it doesn't finish =(

Comment: I looked more deeply and saw that when I run the script in a cmd.exe window, fab.exe is launched by Administrator user and when the server launches it, the owner is SYSTEM. SYSTEM has full control on the fab.exe file so I don't know what to do. Is it possible that the SSH key is only loaded for the Administrator user and not SYSTEM?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Maybe not the best but in a first time, it will be okay.
I added the password in the code in the `env.password` variable of the `fabfile.py` file.

I found that without that a "prompt" was "displayed" by the build server and that stopped the execution waiting for a password!

Thank you for your answer Cinquo. It helped me receiving fabric's outputs =D